# Route not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I was following a tutorial where i view single post but for some reason it see not found expection i don't know what is missing

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

I am trying to access the route through this **URL**

```
http://domain.app/admin/blog/post/2&admin
```

***View Path***

> views -> admin -> blog -> single.blade.php

**Route**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/admin'], function(
Route::get('/blog/post/{post_id}&{$end}', [
    'uses'  => 'PostController@getSinglePost',
    'as'    => 'admin.blog.post'
]);
});
```

**Controller**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\Catgory;

class PostController extends Controller {
public function getSinglePost($post_id, $end = 'frontend') {
    $post = Post::find($post_id);

    if(!$post) {
        return redirect()->route('blog.index')->with(['fail' => 'Post not found']);
    }

    return view ($end, '.blog.single', ['post' => $post]);
}
}
```

Comment: does your view exist? in this case, do you have a file name single.blade.php inside the following folder structure : blog/frontend/

Comment: My view is in  views -> admin -> blog -> single.blade.php .. and you will see in the URL that i pass parameter &admin which should call admin.blog.single

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try it this way?

**ROUTE**

```
<?php 

    // SHOULD MATCH SOMETHING LIKE: /admin/blog/post/1/admin
    // OR:                          /admin/blog/post/1/frontend
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/admin'], function(
        Route::get('/blog/post/{post_id}/{end}', [
            'uses'  => 'PostController@getSinglePost',
            'as'    => 'admin.blog.post'
        ]);
    });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Post;
    use App\Catgory;

    class PostController extends Controller {
        public function getSinglePost($post_id, $end = 'frontend') {
            $post = Post::find($post_id);

            if(!$post) {
                return redirect()->route('blog.index')->with(['fail' => 'Post not found']);
            }
            // YOU ARE CONCATENATING SO NO NEED FOR COMMA...
            return view($end . '.blog.single', ['post' => $post]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **/** instead of **&**...

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/admin'], function(
Route::get('/blog/post/{post_id}/{end}', [
    'uses'  => 'PostController@getSinglePost',
    'as'    => 'admin.blog.post'
]);
});
```

AND your url should be like.....

```
http://domain.app/admin/blog/post/2/admin
```

AND

```
return view ($end.'.blog.single', ['post' => $post]);//remove , and add .
```

Comment: remove `,` from `view()` and add `.`